# How do I start my tests with mock data in SAP Web IDE?

Tags: testing, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have setup an app using SAP Web IDE using my own mock data setup using `metadata.xml`.

The `dataSource` in my `manifest.json` is set up like so...

```json
"dataSources": {
  "NorthwindModel": {
    "uri": "/here/goes/your/serviceurl/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's a dummy URI, but as the app works fine, pulling in the data from my JSON file in `localService/mockdata`, I can't see how this is relevant.

However, the issue I have is, when putting together an integration test using OPA5, the service metadata is never loaded...

```
https://webidetesting1974838-adddcbbb0.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/here/goes/your/serviceurl/$metadata?sap-language=6N
```

(404 not found).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your mockserver needs to be initialized before the component loads. See, for example, https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/9bf4dce43b7943d0909cd6c58a933589. Please show us more details such as the folder structure, HTML documents, QUnit / integration test files, etc. The question is lacking in details which makes answering difficult

Comment: Like I said, even with the above setup when I run Index.html (with Mock data ticked) it pulls in the correct oData from localService/metadata.xml.... However when I run the test opaTest.qunit.html it doesn't have a tick box for mockdata in the run configurations, so the Northwind data is pulled in, and my list object isn't populated.

Comment: In order to find the _cause_, we need the information how your folder structure, HTML files, neo-app.json, run configurations, etc. look like. Please update the question with more details. It's hard to answer without details since Web IDE is no longer freely available to play around.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer?

Run configuration in WEB IDE

I ran the test as a 'Web Application' and ticked 'Mock Data'

No additional libraries needed!